# Is there a non-contact voltage detector component out there?

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, non-contact

Basically, I have a wire that I pulled from my lighting setup across the room. On this side, I would like to turn on the lights when the wire "lights up". The LNG wires on this side all come from the separate breaker box. This one wire, I'm guessing uneducatedly, is a N on the other side's circuits.

Any connecting of that single wire to the circuits on this side results in immediate FID switch disconnect or full (automatic) breaker disconnect, depending on how I connect it. Since the wiring from across the room is old PPR, quite inaccessible, I don't think digging everything up is the way I want to go any more.

Anyway, when I use a phase tester, the wire will "light up" when I turn on the lights, so I DO have some kind of a signal.

But I can't connect just this one wire to a relay.

Exactly how would I go about getting my relay / transistor just from this one wire as its trigger?

The other side of this equasion goes to another relay that actually triggers the lighting power supply. That relay itself is currently already triggered by a separate switch. What I'm trying to achieve here is a "master switch" that would turn on all the lights in the room.

Comment: Try to provide a schematic of the circuit you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for "non-contact voltage detector schematic", you will find circuits built with transistors that drive an LED. These won't work for your purpose since the LED will flicker at the line frequency. You need something that will provide a DC output.

This is a rough concept. It will take a lot of experimentation to get this to work. The opamp needs to be ultra-high impedance.

Connecting DIY circuits to the mains is dangerous. Personally, I would never connect DIY circuits permanently to the mains, too much liability. But, I might build this as a learning experience someday.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnc1fJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>